# Understanding and solving git Conflict "File mode changed"

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge-conflict

I work normally on git... I create my branch, work on it... Merge into develop... solve conflicts... create PR
But when I go to bit-bucket I see that it shows a lot of conflicts due to:

"Conflict: File mode changed in both source and destination"

Both files apparently are the same, except in the content:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 98085 sep 28 13:16 path/to/file.py in develop
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 99893 sep 28 13:16 path/to/file.py in my branch
```

And I don't understand this conflict or how to resolve it, and I mean resolve, not ignore with `git config core.fileMode false`.

Comment: Rebase instead of merge could solve this. Otherwise it could handled like other merge conflicts...

Comment: I can't solve it normally because in my terminal can't see the conflict, and I don't know what to do... change permissions? the end of line?

Comment: So what's your `git status`?

Comment: the normal 'your branch is up to date', 'nothing to commit' 'working tree clean'

Comment: This error doesn't make much sense to me, since Git stores only one bit of "mode" per file. A merge will have three inputs: merge base, tip1, tip2. If the mode changed from base to tip1, then it went from -x to +x or from +x to -x. If the mode changed from base to tip2, it necessarily had the *same change*. These two changes *cannot* conflict. Perhaps bitbucket are referring to file-mode (symlink to ordinary file) rather than "file mode" (-x vs +x)?

Comment: In any case, the obvious thing to do is to find the merge base commit and inspect `path/to/file.py` there.

Comment: Inspect what @torek? what is the error? file permissions? end of line?...

Comment: The entry for `path/to/file.py` in the merge base, i.e., what "mode" you get for that in that particular commit. Comparing that with the output you get for the two tip commits (similar to the above) should tell us what bitbucket is griping about. So: `git merge-base --all branch1 branch2` (get the commit hash ID), then `git ls-tree -r` on each of the three commits and extract the three lines of interest.

Comment: For instance: `git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep path/to/file` might turn up `100644 blob cc46fc918955220eea72d2fa5839909a41000712 path/to/file`. The mode is 100644 here. Mode should always be one of 100644, 100755 (regular files), 120000 (symlink), and very rarely 160000 (gitlink = submodule) or 040000 (tree, i.e., you had a directory before).

Answer (score 1):

(note: not an answer, more of a formatted comment)

There is also a notion of "filemode" within git storage itself.

Can you compare :

```
git ls-tree <commit>:path/to/
```

when replacing `<commit>` with `develop`, `branch` and `<base commit id>`, and see what "filemode" appears for `file.py` ?

---

The output should be something like :

```
# taken from github.com/git/git :
$ git ls-tree HEAD:xdiff/
100644 blob bb56b23f34c96ceec169d39b829e89cd512d7e39    xdiff.h
100644 blob 32652ded2d7c5cad87f120a13c3c6c84d6def61f    xdiffi.c
100644 blob 126c9d8ff4e4147e0f4e96ddb9debfde17d9b637    xdiffi.h
            # etc ...
#  ^
# that filemode
```

Comment: all looks correct, but I'm going to investigate with that command, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have just had a similar issue, with Bitbucket saying "Conflict: File mode changed in both source and destination" for one file. This message turned out to be misleading. `git ls-tree` showed the same file mode for the relevant file in both branches and in the merge base.

In the end I followed the process [Resolve merge conflicts](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/resolve-merge-conflicts/), which showed conflicts in the *content* of the file. I fixed these and the conflict was resolved.

Comment: We also encountered the same issue with Bitbucket erroneously showing a "Conflict: File mode changed" message, when in reality it was a genuine content conflict that was easily revealed using local tooling.